# While insert the new record, the insert values are stored as NULL in all fields except auto increment ID in mysql

Tags: mysql, null, innodb, myisam

While insert the new record, the insert values are stored as NULL in all fields except auto increment ID in MySQL

[image]

Comment: Maybe if you show us the insert command we can help.

Comment: ... and the definition of the table as well.